# how to build jquery-mobile from source?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Jquery-mobile 1.5.rc1 is released in git, but it is not available in
http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Downloaded jquery-mobile 1.5.rc1 from github. how to build jquery-mobile from source?

I needed the following for 1.4.5.

```
jquery.mobile.css
jquery.mobile.min.css
jquery.mobile.js
jquery.mobile.min.js
jquery.mobile.structure.css
jquery.mobile.structure.min.css
jquery.mobile.icons.css
jquery.mobile.icons.min.css
/images/**
```

Now migrating to 1.5.

Comment: Searched maven repository, not found

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is available.

Just choose Latest and you will get RC1.

Comment: I can select rc1. but download builder is not working.

Comment: Its dev seems active.

Comment: Let me give you a better perspective. jQuery Mobile 1.5 beta was released 2 years and 2 months ago. It was announced 4 years ago. This was before the AngularJS team started working on Angular 2 (which is now in version 8). During all this time jQuery Mobile 1.5 is still in beta. At best you can call it living dead.